# Intermediate results in a recursive function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function which will find all prime numbers from 2 to 100. I can do so by testing if a number is prime by looking at remainder when the number `n` is divided by all numbers in `2..n-1`.

I would however like only to test against prime numbers I have already found. This is how far I got writing my recursive function, but I don't know how to replace `[2..t-1]` with the prime numbers I have already worked out (the intermediate result of my recursive function I guess). How can I do that?

```
primes = go [2..100]
    where
        go l@(t:ts)
            | all (\x -> t `rem` x /= 0) [2..t-1] = t:(go ts)
            | otherwise = go ts
        go [] = []

main = print primes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with tail recursion. Where you carry the already calculated primes `ps` along.

```
primes = go [2..100] []
    where go (t:ts) ps
            | all (\x -> (t `rem` x) /= 0) ps = go ts (t:ps)
            | otherwise = go ts ps
          go [] ps = ps
```

Note that primes are now reversed. It is faster to concatenate them than appending it.

You can also limit the number of divisions:

```
| all (\x -> (t `rem` x) /= 0) (takeWhile (\x -> x*x <= t) ps) = go ts (t:ps)
```

Also use `Int` if speed matters because it is unboxed.

Comment: One of my attempts was virtually the same but I kept getting `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 ~ [a1]` error. The only difference was that you had `()` around `t:ps`. I put `()` in and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possible way:

```
primes = 2 : go [3..]
    where
        go (t:ts)
            | all (\x -> t `rem` x /= 0) (takeWhile (\x->x*x<=t) primes)  = t:(go ts)
            | otherwise = go ts
```

Here we use the already-calculated part of `primes` up to the square root of `t`. Note that we need not to specify the upper bound in `primes`, it will simply produce an infinite list that you can later chop:

```
print $ take 1000 primes
```

Note also that we need to bootstrap `primes` such that the very first prime is not calculated from previous primes, so that `takeWhile` could work.

Comment: I assume that Haskell remembers the prime numbers already calculated with `primes` so you can just take up to the square root without recalculation?

Comment: @TomTom yes, exactly.